# GWT RPC is not working in Opera at IDN

Tags: gwt, opera, gwt-rpc, idn

GWT RPC requests fail in Opera when site has international domain name.

The error message is as follows:

> Unable to initiate the asynchronous service invocation
>   (GreetingService_Proxy.getDate) -- check the network connection
>
> (DOMException) code: 12 INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1 DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2
>   HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3 WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4 INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR:
>   5 NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6 NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7 NOT_FOUND_ERR:
>   8 NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9 INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10 INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11
>   SYNTAX_ERR: 12 INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13 NAMESPACE_ERR: 14
>   INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15 VALIDATION_ERR: 16 TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17
>   SECURITY_ERR: 18 NETWORK_ERR: 19 ABORT_ERR: 20 URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21
>   QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22 TIMEOUT_ERR: 23 INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24
>   DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25: SYNTAX_ERR

How could this be solved?

Comment: I suppose it fails with an error message?

Comment: Yes, I have added it to the question.

Comment: Which version of Opera are you using? Does a simple XMLHttpRequest works? E.g. in the console of Dragonfly `var xhr = new XMLHttprequest(); xhr.open('GET', window.location.href); xhr.send(); xhr.responseText` That code worked for me at one of http://idn.icann.org/#The_example.test_names in Opera 12.11.1661 on Linux x86_64 (Ubuntu 12.10)